# mod_security blocking SOAP client simulation

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-security, xml, soap

I'm writing a PHP SOAP server and I'm using PAW ( mac app ) to simulate SOAP client request

on my local server I get a SOAP response on production server a get an 403 Forbidden error, since on this server I did have previous issue with mod security is the firth thing i thought. In log file i get a 403 error and then

> ModSecurity: XML parser error: XML: Failed parsing document. [hostname "www.mydomain.com"] [uri "/mypath/push-products.php"] [unique_id "123456789"]
>
> ModSecurity: Access denied with code 403 (phase 2). Match of "eq 0" against "REQBODY_ERROR" required. [file "/etc/httpd/modsec/00_asl_z_antievasion.conf"] [line "36"] [id "330791"] [msg "Failed to parse request body. This may be an impedence mismatch attack, a broken application or a broken connection. This is not a false positive. Check your application or client for errors."] [data "XML parser error: XML: Failed parsing document."] [severity "CRITICAL"] [hostname "www.mydomain.com"] [uri "/mypath/push-products.php"] [unique_id "123456789"]

how can disable mod security check on this folder via .htaccess?

Comment: This is an error with your request headers. What are the headers you are setting?

Comment: Is Content-Type application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8 i followed this https://paw.cloud/docs/getting-started/soap-request

Comment: Right, it says it is not getting correct XML. I suspect this is a malformed request but you can turn of mod_security for a folder with this in the vhost definition: `<Directory /var/www/whatever>
  SecRuleEngine Off
</Directory>`

Comment: is not possible via .htaccess?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12928360/how-can-i-disable-mod-security-in-htaccess-file

Comment: that doesn't work but this does <IfModule security2_module>
 SecRuleRemoveById 330791
</IfModule>